# Deploying SQL Server & Web App to Azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

Can someone please tell me how to create my own SQL server database, & host it on Microsoft Azure?

I've followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-portal

But, it just shows you how to make essentially a copy of Microsoft's template database.

Can you please tell me how to deploy an SQL server database to Azure?

I know how to create a local web app, & then add a database to that later on, but I don't know how to deploy it to Azure?

Comment: You can [connect SSMS directly to Azure.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-ssms)

Comment: I haven't used SQL Server Management Studio before, but I have added .mdf files in Visual Studio before.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/cd/deploy-dacpac-sqlpackage. It's for .NET but it may give you an idea. SSMS is free though, so now is as good a time as any to install it and familiarize yourself with a SQL back end if you are developing an application utilizing it.

Comment: Hi @JacobH, I'll give SSMS a go then. Before I try to connect to a server in SSMS, I first need to create a server in the first place. Can you tell me how I go about doing that in Azure? As the first link you gave explains how to use the database after it has been published.

Comment: @JacobH The part that's catching me out in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-portal is when they supply the "source" as they use the AdventureWorksLT schema

Comment: If you have already gone through the tutorial to create a database then it should be available to connect to in Azure. You just need to follow the steps to whitelist your computer in the Azure options, then connect via SSMS.

Comment: I've gone through the tutorial, & yes, that database is available, but I don't want that database as the source schema is the sample one which Microsoft have. I want to know how to use my own schema

Comment: Use this tutorial instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-design-first-database The other one shows you how to use the Microsoft template database called "Adventureworks". Which is helpful for learning because a lot of the MS docs reference Adventureworks databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to portal.azure.com

1) create sql server

[image]

2) after that, select the newly created sql server and then click on New Database

3) when the database is created, select the sql server again, go to properties, note admin login and server name

4) add your ip in sql server firewall settings

5) remotely connect to the server using your sql server management studio by providing server name and admin login noted in step#3

6) run create database script